# Потеря данных при их передаче методом GET запроса

Tags: php, http, php-curl

У меня есть 2 сервера, которые общаются между собой с помощью http-запросов. Для выполнения запросов я использую php curl. Проблема возникает при получении данных методом GET со второго сервера:

1. Первый сервер отправляет второму серверу GET запрос.
2. Второй сервер формирует массив с данными и сериализирует его (serialize).
3. Второй сервер отдает сериализированные данные с помощью echo.
4. Первый сервер получает эти данные.

Периодически получается так, что часть данных обрезается. Конец выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В то время как конец сериализированных данных должен выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень прошу помощи, так как даже нет предположений, из-за чего данные могут обрезаться.
На серверах timeout установлен с запасом: set_time_limit(28800);
Так же выделен большой объем памяти, превышающий передаваемые данные: ini_set('memory_limit','8192M');

В дополнению к этому get запрос может зависнуть до ручного завершения. Например, может спокойно висеть 3 дня. А это в несколько раз превышает установленный timeout.

Первый сервер выполняет запрос следующим образом:

```
$Curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // Skip SSL Verification
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Skip SSL Verification
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET_FILES');

$aHeaders = array();
$aHeaders[] = 'query: '.$sUrlParams;
$aHeaders[] = 'Content-Type: 0';

curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aHeaders);
$result = curl_exec($Curl);
```

Второй сервер на этот запрос делает:

```
$sResponse = serialize($aResponseBody); 
echo $sResponse;
```

Comment: а не надо гет-запросом данные длинные передавать, он для этого не предназначен и собственно имеет ограничения, которые от места к месту могут быть различны. используйте post. особенно с учетом того, что передаете что-то не особо текстовое, судя по всему

Comment: какой у вас стек?

Comment: @teran Так автор написал что возникает "периодически", тестит судя по всему на одинаковых данных, значит проблема не в том что get превышает максимальное к-ство символов. Как по мне более странно что у автора гет запрос висит 3 дня.

Comment: @teran длина ответа на GET запрос ничем не ограничена. URL GET запроса да, ограничена 2048 символами, но это не применимо здесь. Автор, как вы реализуете передачу данных и их получение? Приведите код.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov пардон, что-то я решил что оно это в запросе передает. про длину ответа я ничего не писал

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, дополнил вопрос

Comment: А есть статистика, на каком символе обрубаются данные? Мож попадается какой-то типа служебного символа, который прерывает строку?

Comment: @DrMcSheen, к сожалению, нет.